# Is it possible pass a function to Chakra's isInvalid property?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I have a controlled Chakra input component. If I set the isInvalid prop to a boolean I can control its appearance correctly.

```
<Input
  isInvalid={true}
  name="nmfc"
  value={inputs.nmfc}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

However as soon as I pass a function it always appears as invalid, even if the function evaluates to false.

```
<Input
  isInvalid={() => inputs.nmfc === 'illegalvalue'}
  name="nmfc"
  value={inputs.nmfc}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

I have also tried passing a variable to the property, but changes to the variable aren't reflected.

It seems like it should be possible to set this dynamically, since whether an input is valid depends on changing input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass in the evaluation should work:

```
<Input
  isInvalid={inputs.nmfc === 'illegalvalue'}
  name="nmfc"
  value={inputs.nmfc}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: Oh great! Thank you